# How view HTTP requests from Angular app in Chrome?

Tags: angular

How view HTTP requests from Angular app in Chrome DevTools?

I need to get a post request when I add item.

Answer (score 3):

press f12 and choose **Network** tab . then select **XHR** . u can see all HTTP requests .

Comment: When I add new item on the requests page does not appear

Comment: do u recieve the request on your server ?

Comment: It's not my server. All works, but requests not logging

Comment: Also, make sure to open the tab first, and *then* perform the query.

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal exactly . Network tab logs only when is opened

Comment: Screencast: take.ms/yamGN

Comment: in your video u edited one item and chrome logged the request , right ?

Comment: Edit item, but chrome not logged it

Comment: can i see the method that sends the http post request ?

Comment: how i can detect method? its not my website

Comment: Can u give me the website link ?

Answer (score 0):

Press `F12` in your browser and go into `Network` Tab.

You can view all the requests.